# How to give styles for Angular 2 primeng auto search textbox?

Tags: css, angular5

Hi I have implemented auto search option in Angular 2 using primeng. I have found reference in https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete site. when I implement same code in my project I do not see suggestions filling in drop-down box list. I have added screenshot below.

[image: Auto Search]

Below is my code.

```
<p-autoComplete autofocus name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" [suggestions]="filteredUsernamesSingle"(completeMethod)="filterUsernameSingle($event)" field="userName" [size]="30"
placeholder="Enter UserName" [minLength]="3" required></p-autoComplete>
```

In reference website when user tries to search some test, everything comes in dro-down list. But when I implement I am not getting any drop-down list as I shown in above image. Can someone help me where can I add styles to make suggestions come in drop-down box list?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was passing a string[] array into [suggestions]. After examining their [example](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/showcase/components/autocomplete) it started working after I started passing an array of objects instead. Apparently the autocomplete component expects an object with a property specified in the field directive, otherwise it can't reach the value and format it properly. Try passing it an object with a userName property, since in the HTML you specified field="userName".

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation page [primefaces getting started](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup). You'll see instructions to add the primeng css and primeicons and a theme css file that you will use as the theme for your site, to the project's angular.js file. This will work like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />` embedding of external css files to a web page.